# Replace Line Feed in Regex Expression

Tags: regex, vb.net

I don't know much about regex and don't have much need to know, but I have a particular scenario I'm hoping someone can help with. Here's what I need to do:

1. For each occurrence of a single line feed -- that is, not two consecutive line feeds -- strip it.
2. For each occurrence of multiple consecutive line feeds, replace it with a single line feed.

Is there an expression or a couple of expressions that can be used to do this?

Comment: [`Regex.Replace(s, "(\r?\n){2,}|\r?\n", "$1")`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5cr%3f%5cn%29%7b2%2c%7d%7c%5cr%3f%5cn&i=1%0d%0a2%0d%0a%0d%0a3&r=%241)

Comment: Works beautifully Wiktor, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
Regex.Replace(s, "(\r?\n){2,}|\r?\n", "$1")
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5cr%3f%5cn%29%7b2%2c%7d%7c%5cr%3f%5cn&i=1%0d%0a2%0d%0a%0d%0a3&r=%241).

**Details**

- `(\r?\n){2,}` - 2 or more CRLF/LF line break sequences (the capturing group here only captures a single instance of CRLF/LF, and the last one captured will remain in the resulting string, inserted with `$1`)
- `|` - or (if the preceding alternative did not match)
- `\r?\n` - a single CRLF/LF line break

Comment: Thank you for the explanation as well!